# Fixing intersecting arrows in commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, scaling, commutative-diagrams

The following is the code for a commutative diagram with intersecting arrows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref,letterpaper=true,colorlinks=true,pdfpagemode=none,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge]
    (X, \mathcal{T}) 
        \arrow{r}{\text{Id}_X} 
        \arrow{d}{q'} 
        \arrow[swap]{dr}{f_3 \circ q'} 
    & (X, \mathcal{T}) 
        \arrow{dr}{f_1 \circ q'} 
        \arrow{r}{\text{Id}_X} 
        \arrow{d}{q'} 
        \arrow{r}{\text{Id}_X} 
    &  (X, \mathcal{T}) 
        \arrow{d}{q} 
        \arrow{dl}{f_2 \circ q} \\
    (Y, \mathcal{T}) 
        \arrow{r}{f_3} 
    & (Y, \mathcal{T}) 
        \arrow{r}{f_1} 
        \arrow[r,<-,shift right,swap, "f_2"]{f_2} 
    & (Y, \mathcal{Q}) 
\end{tikzcd}

\]



\end{document}
```

Which generates the following below. My question is how can I make the text on the right square look better?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the affiliation clear you could put the label on the slope.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\DeclareMathOperator\Id{Id}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge]
    (X, \mathcal{T}) 
        \arrow{r}{\Id_X} 
        \arrow{d}{q'} 
        \arrow[swap]{dr}{f_3 \circ q'} 
    & (X, \mathcal{T}) 
        \arrow[sloped,pos=.1]{dr}{f_1 \circ q'} 
        \arrow{r}{\Id_X} 
        \arrow{d}{q'} 
        \arrow{r}{\Id_X} 
    &  (X, \mathcal{T}) 
        \arrow{d}{q} 
        \arrow[sloped,pos=.3]{dl}{f_2 \circ q} \\
    (Y, \mathcal{T}) 
        \arrow{r}{f_3} 
    & (Y, \mathcal{T}) 
        \arrow{r}{f_1} 
        \arrow[r,<-,shift right,swap, "f_2"]{f_2} 
    & (Y, \mathcal{Q}) 
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a reason the $f_1 \circ q'$ has been rendered less clearly as compared to $f_2 \circ q$?